# Google maps on mobile - initial tiles showing when moving

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cordova

So I'm building an app with Google Maps API v3 for my maps. I came across this strange bug. When moving my finger on the map, the initial tiles displayed when loading shows up as if it was the default loading images. This results in a very disturbing outcome. See the video below :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvmgXRpr7ng

Very confusing...

Here is the code if needed. Simplest code ever :

```
function GoogleMap(){

    this.initialize = function(){
        var map = showMap();
    }

    var showMap = function(){
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        return map;
    }
}

function onDeviceReady(){
    var map = new GoogleMap();
    map.initialize();
}
```

I'm using the latest Cordova (Phonegap) release and the showed example is recorded in a Google Nexus 5 running Android 4.4.2.

Thanks ahead for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue of not centring, and displays only part of map on map canvas.
Put it line after `map.initialize();`

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

And after that do **setCenter** and **setZoom** again

```
map.setCenter(myLatlng);
map.setZoom(10);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  will try it in a few weeks (can't before) and if it works I will come back to mark it as good answer :)